# High-Resolution VLC Visualization Ouput

Tags: vlc-media-player, visualization

I would like to use a VLC visualization to render an image large enough for printing.  Is there any way to redirect the output of each frame to disk, rather than to the screen?  If so, I could set the resolution very high and wait.

Obviously, frame rate is not an issue.  If it has to crank for a half-hour per frame, that'd be fine with me.

Ideally, I'd like to output frames of 3375x5175 pixels, but I can go down to half that size if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Related:  http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=59381